# why we should always return resource or DTO in Spring Rest for GET, PUT, POST?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I am developing ***Spring Boot + Spring Rest + HATEOAS + Data JPA*** heavily in my project. While developing Spring REST Endpoints I have always been told to return DTO/Resource object and not actual entity object.

Is there any specific reason we should always return DTO/Resource Object (not Entity object which maps to DB Table).?

Answer (score 3):

Because it may contains additional (internal) properties that you don't want to expose to the client.

Separating it into two types avoids the concern of deciding which properties to serialize and which not. It also means that the resource objects are truly POJOs, who doesn't contain any logic concerning your internal properties, and are used only to represent the client's requests and responses.